# creating xml files based on XSD using java xml framework

Tags: java, xml, xsd

which Java XML framework would be the best to create all possible XML files based on specified XSD file.

Comment: with a typical schema, "all possible" might exceed tens of thousands. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: yes, for testing purpose

Comment: It may easily exceed tens of quadrillions. Think about a single string of a dozen characters (26^12=1e17, if you only consider simple letters).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has tools for doing this and is probably free.

Once you've got the right version of Eclipse, open the existing schema file for editing (or create a new one: select File -> New... Other ... XML / XML Schema ). When you're ready to generate a test XML file, locate the file in the Package Explorer (the navigator view, usually on the left side), right click on it, and select Generate/XML File.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_schema_editor.html) is a tool that can generate xml files from xsd.

[XMLBeans tools](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#xsd2inst) seem to offer this, too.

[And something called "trang"](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/) appears to be able to do this.

Comment: @Laxmikanth Samudrala Why do you need run-time generation? Won't static generation do?

Comment: it's a large file and some real data want to set while creating the XML

Comment: that doesn't answer why it needs to be at run-time

Comment: @Laxmikanth Samudrala  then you can use Oxygen to do it